# Error illegal character '\u0650'

Tags: android

i had that error :
Error:(55, 13) error: illegal character: '\u0650'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
while i was trying to make retry button in my app 
and this is my code

```
private void CallNetwork(String baseUrl) {
    if (NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
        new Url_cont(this, getActivity()).execute(baseUrl);
    } else {
        ِAlertDialog.Builder alert= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alert.setTitle("Error !!!");
        alert.setMessage("sorry there is no connection please check your internet and retry");
        AlertDialog alertDialog =alert.create();
        alert.setPositiveButton("Retry",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.dismiss();
                CallNetwork(MovieUrl);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"network unavailble!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

my devices is google nexus 7 api 23 
and the error in

```
            ِAlertDialog.Builder alert= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

i need solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

i finally now the answer

```
 {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("No Internet");
        builder.setMessage("Internet is required. Please Retry.");
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                CallNetwork(MovieUrl);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Unavailable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

this code is better and it work good so if you want to make retry button just use this code and this error will show again